# Higher resistance resistor in place of higher wattage?

Tags: led, resistors, raspberry-pi, breadboard

Engineering newbie here. I'm fairly sure I already know the answer to the question, but I figure I'll ask anyway.

I've got an LED lying around, that according to an LED calculator requires a 80R 1/2w resistor. However, I don't have any 1/2w resistors laying around. I do have like a hundred different 1/4w resistors laying around of varying resistance.

Using a higher resistance would not make up for the lower wattage, correct? The amperage would still likely overheat and blow up the resistor?

I'm fairly sure this is true, just wanting to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Power on the resistor will be \$I^2R\$. Using an higher resistance will  lower the wattage as in the formula above, but your led will not shine too much. You can solve the problem by using two  1/4 w resistors in parallel of 160 Ohm to have a single resistance value of 80 Ohm with 1/2 W power, but of course you really won't do that, because making your circuit so ugly just to save a resistor it is not a good idea.

Comment: Using two resistors in parallel to increase the power is not ugly, it's common practice and often implemented because it can save you components in the BOM and spread the heat over a larger area, making it easier to get rid of.

Comment: Or two 40Ω 1/4 W resistors in series.

Answer (score 1):

If you connect two 160Ω 1/4W resistors in parallel, they will be equivalent to one 80Ω 1/2W resistor.

Actually the nearest standard values would be 150Ω or 180Ω. Go with the larger ones if you have them, to be conservative.

Comment: In parallel, and far enough away that they don't mutually heat each other.

Comment: 150Ω in parallel with 180Ω has a resistance of just under 82Ω, and if the resistors are 1/4 W types and don't mutually heat, the effective power rating of the combination is 0.458 W.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the correct value resistor for the LED or the LED will burn out, as will having an under rated resistor displacing too much power cause the resistor to burn up.

However if I understand your situation correctly you may be able to do something like this if you want:

If you need an 80 ohm resistor that can handle 1/2 watt you can take...

1. 4x 80 ohm 1/4 Watt resistors and
2. twist two together, do this twice
3. then take the two twisted pairs and put them in series

This will give you an 1W 80 Ohm resistor equivalent.

Comment: Increasing the resistance, as proposed in the question, will not burn out the LED -- it may not shine (or shine poorly), but it won't burn out.